# ASP date format using client culture code-behind

Tags: asp.net, linq, date, format, globalization

I have an ASP.NET web application and data in a `SQLServer` DB.

What is the best way to display a date (extracted with LINQ) in the client's culture format, from code-behind.

I mean I have users from USA and from Europe, they want different formats: `MM/dd/yyyy` (US) or `dd/MM/yyyy (UK)`?

What I would like is something like:

```
from myData in dbContext.myFile 
         Where .../... 
   Select myFile.birthDate.ToString.(**some magic formating here**)
```

Update: Thanks to Darin for quick answer!

Tip:  if using IE, don't forget to check what is the preferred lang in use: 
Look in Tools / Internet options / Languages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could set the culture to auto in the [`<globalization>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx) element of your web.config:

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
```

which will use the culture of the client browser. Then simply use `.ToString()`:

```
<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
```

or `ToShortDateString` depending on the format you want.

Comment: Loks nice! Could you please tell me in which part of the web.config file to insert that line?

Comment: @DidierLevy, inside `<system.web>`.

Comment: I did the change but unfortunately, the program is still using the server's culture settings!!! e.g. server is in the US and though I have a french computer, date displays like M/d/yyyy.

Comment: It works! My bad: I had US settings in my local Internet-Explorer. Changed it to french and now all is fine. +1 vote for you Darin :-)