# .NET App using US Dates instead EU Dates

Tags: c#, .net, date

I have a app which takes a date from datepicker and then displays this on screen. It worked fine everywhere but on this new cloud server if I pick a date in september it's displaying as

09-Apr-2014 16:52 to 09-Jun-2014 16:52

When it should be

04-Sep-2014 to 06-Sep-2014

Is there a setting in web.config I can change to make the App using european date settings ?

Comment: There are multiple ways to handle this.  Web.config settings to fix your app to a particular culture is one approach, but I would argue that a well-designed app would work well in *any* culture.  Please show the relevant code for your date-picker, how it's populated, and how you parse input from it.

Comment: This is not "seeking debugging help".  The question asks about how to change localization settings through web.config.

Comment: @MattJohnson: The OP never says that the application *breaks*, he says that it displays a date with the wrong localization setting for his users.

Comment: @Eric - Sure, but without more details, setting the culture to a fixed value may be the wrong advice. For example, many date-pickers need the date in ISO format. Or perhaps the picker uses client-side script and expects the server-side data to match locales, in which case [automatic culture detection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7777707/634824) might be more appropriate. It's hard to give good advice since we don't know which date picker is being used or how it's being populated. Though your answer does match the very last sentence asked, it might not be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your location in your web.config.  Otherwise, the OS defaults are used.

> In an ASP.NET Web page, you can set to two culture values, the Culture and UICulture properties. The Culture value determines the results of culture-dependent functions, such as the date, number, and currency formatting, and so on. The UICulture value determines which resources are loaded for the page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bz9tc508(v=vs.100).aspx

For the UK, I believe your entry would be

```
<globalization culture="en-GB"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web-application, you can set:

```
<system.web>
   ...
   <globalization culture="de-CH" uiCulture="de-CH" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8"/>
   ...
</system.web>
```

in the web.config file.

Or you can add an inline-script in the aspx page. 
This is useful if you don't have the sourcecode and don't want to set a static culture, 
(e.g. when you want to switch the language of ReportServer.aspx based on a Request.QueryString-parameter instead of the language set in the browser):

```
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    string lang = "de-CH";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang );
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
            CultureInfo(lang );
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
</script>
```

Or you can statically set the culture on the page itselfs

```
<%@ Page UICulture="de" Culture="de-CH" %>
```

Note that this particular nuisance for some reasons sometimes doesn't go away if you set the culture in the web.config file (happened to me when installing our application on an "en-US" server of the Swiss National Broadcasting Company).

Then you need to create a new base-class and inherit from System.Web.UI.Page, and not allow override in the constructor (the ,False)

```
Public MustInherit Class claPageBaseForm
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub New()
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, False)
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, False)
    End Sub
```

C# code for that, if you need it

```
public /* abstract */ class claPageBaseForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected claPageBaseForm()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.
CurrentCulture.Name, false);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.
CurrentCulture.Name, false);
    }

}
```

Then on your web-page codebehind, you inherit from the base-class instead of System.Web.UI.Page

```
partial class YourPage: claPageBaseForm
{

}
```

instead of

```
partial class YourPage: System.Web.UI.Page
{

}
```

That's the fastest way to combat it, as you can do it with search-and-replace in the source-code.
Having a common base-page is anyway useful.

Also, note that this "feature" can also affect class libraries (string.Format(`Insert INTO TABLE WHATEVER '{0}', dateTime.ToString())`), therefore setting it on the page may not be sufficient (if the current day is < 13, it might even just save garbage in your database, and not return an error - plus it can also retrieve garbage on select!)

Comment: Mixed VB/C#?  OP tagged C#.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it may be better to default to the language preferences specified by the browser, in this way you will get the correct culture depending on user preferences.

```
 <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true"/>
```

Comment: While technically true, that might be the worst possible idea, if the date-handling isn't done properly in the backend (SQL ISO-Date-Format), and front-end (JavaScript). Also, that enables unwanted "features", like switching to english date format if you sit at a computer in an internet caffee in new-york and enter German/British date-format (as a European in New York). It also makes you interprete the outputted dates wrongly if you just look at the data sitting in an internet coffee in NYC as a european. Automating this ain't a good idea, it's the highway to (i18n) hell.

Comment: all of these choices are dependent on the actual requirements and what may work for one may not work for another. Notice I said "may be better"